What tool can I use to cut through this material behind drywall?
I'm trying to find a water leak behind a wall.  My oscillating multitool cut through the drywall nicely but there seems to be a thick sheet behind it. How do I cut through that?  Just force the multitool?  My multitool came with a Bi-Metal blade and a HCS blade.


Drill a small hole (carefully, so as not to cause additional plumbing leaks) and use a borescope. That's a small camera that fits through a small hole these days, and pretty affordable.

what is your location on this planet?  That doesn't look like plywood.

+1 that looks like some kind of fiberboard.

I agree--that's not plywood. I'd want to know why it's there. Is it sound insulation?

Good luck matching that color and texture later.

Fibrous material may clog your saw blade teeth. You need a saw with a longer stroke so it cleans itself out, such as a reciprocating saw, or you need a simple utility knife with a fresh blade.
In short, use whatever you have that gets the job done (up to and including a hammer). Pull the nails and pop it out whole so you can reinstall it, or plan to replace it with something of the same thickness.

+1 for pulling the nails and reusing the whole board.  Enlarging the drywall cutout and doing this will probably net the least work overall.

Is this potentially an asbestos containing product?

Of course. I have no idea where or when you are, so... anything's possible.

If that is cement board, cut two opposite sides with a hacksaw, score the other two with a knife and kick it out.  Wear a mask and don't use power tools.

Sorry, a hasty answer, I think this is the easiest way to make the hole so I'll leave it.  But thinking through to refinishing, I would go with the approach from Isherwood. whole board.
